# Logical operator in if statement

Tags: c

Why does this statement returns TRUE? I thought C reads statement from left to right. What is the output of (i == 20) that results to 30 is TRUE?

```
i = 10;
if(i == 20 || 30)
{
    printf("True");
}
else
{
    printf("False");
}
```

Comment: `i == 20 || 30` is `(i == 20) || 30`. And `30` is a truthy value.

Comment: in C every value other than binary 0 causes the conditional to evaluate as true. there's no concepts of "true" and "false" just 0 and everything else.

Answer (score 7):

This: `if(i == 20 || 30)` is equivalent to `if((i == 20) || 30)` and `30` is always `true`.

If you really want to do what I think you want to do, you should have written:

```
if(i == 20 || i == 30)
```

instead.

Comment: What is the output of (i==20) that results to TRUE?

Comment: (i == 20) is `false`, but this does not matter, since `30` evaluates to `true` and you use logical `or` operator.